The problem of compiler conflict between Cuda projects and a regular C++ project
I have one Solution and two projects in it: Cuda and NumsRec. When you add the Matrix.cuh header file from the Cuda project to one of the .cpp files of the NumsRec project, all the code begins to compile through the compiler used for regular .cpp files, which causes the Cuda syntax to cease to be recognized because the compiler does not support CUDA-specific syntax.
/SolutionRoot
    -| CMakeLists.txt             
    -| /Cuda
        -| CMakeLists.txt        
        -| Matrix.cuh
    -| /NumsRec
        -| CMakeLists.txt            
        -| main.cpp
        -| MLP.cpp
        -| Layer.cpp
        -| MLP.h
        -| Layer.h

SolutionRoot/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(ProjectRoot)

add_subdirectory(Cuda)
add_subdirectory(NumsRec)

SolutionRoot/Cuda/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CudaLib LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES native)

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    init.cu 
    Matrix.cuh 
)

set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES 
    CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION on
)

target_compile_options(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:--extended-lambda>
)

link_directories(${CUDAToolkit_LIBRARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC 
    cuda.lib
)

target_include_directories (
    ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

SolutionRoot/NumsRec/CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(NumsRec LANGUAGES СXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(SOURCE 
    main.cpp
    MLP.cpp
    Layer.cpp
    MLP.h
    Layer.h
)

add_executable(NumsRec ${SOURCE})

target_link_libraries(
    NumsRec 
    PUBLIC
    CudaLib
)

target_include_directories(
    NumsRec
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Cuda
)

Dont know if it is possible to use MSVC compiler for NumsRec and CUDA compiler for cuda

Saw on NVIDIA forum they say that .cuh normally should be excluded from the build, because they are "just header files". On linux that may be an issue with make dist  functionality,

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#x-c-c-cu-x

.cuh headers (i.e. headers that contain CUDA  C++ code) should only be included in .cu source files so the build tools know how to compile these source files. Due to nvcc sometimes failing on more complicated C++ constructs, one wants to avoid compiling all the C++ code with nvcc. So depending on the content, it might make sense to have Cuda/Matrix.cu and Cuda/Matrix.h where only contains the C++ host interface to the CUDA code in Matrix.cu.

"all the code begins to compile through the compiler used for regular .cpp files" you mean all the C++ code in NumsRec is still compiled with your C++ compiler? I would be surprized if CMake does not invoke nvcc for init.cu.

I forgot to mention that Matrix.cuh contains template functions so realization of this functions is also in Matrix.cuh

You can still do explicit template instantiation in Matrix.cu and link it if you prefer not to rename all the .cpp files to .cu

I tried to do it but still does not work.
Example:
// main.cpp
#include "Matrix.cuh"
main.cpp compiles with MSVC and the cuda code written in Matrix.cuh and Matrix.cu also starts to compile in MSVC.
Here is how full project looks like:
https://github.com/w1zZzyy/nvcc-msvc-problem

I can't reproduce the issue on Linux (it compiles fie and uses nvcc for Matrix.cu) and I don't have a Windows development environment at hand.
